# Drupal registered user page?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-themes

I have a drupal site that I am creating right now. 
I have 3 roles, and these are:
Anonymous
Authenticated
Registered Users

On my "Registered Users" I wanted to have a different theme after they login. Do you have ideas on how to achieve this?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
on hook_init
if global $user have role Registred
global $theme = 'theme_x';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://drupal.org/project/themekey

It should allow you to change the theme based on role of user.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a completely different theme is a quite drastic method. If possible, I would try to use a single theme, set a class on the body tag indicating the user role and style those pages differently with just CSS.